# Curl Equivalent in Python

Tags: python, linux, curl

I have a python program that takes pictures and I am wondering how I would write a program that sends those pictures to a particular URL.

If it matters, I am running this on a Raspberry Pi.

(Please excuse my simplicity, I am very new to all this)

Comment: Probably using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Many folks turn to the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for this sort of thing.

For something lower level, you might use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the requests package as well. Here's an [example POST](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) from the requests documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling that you want to use CURL, try [PyCurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

Install it using:

> sudo pip install pycurl

Here is an example of how to send data using it:

```
import pycurl
import json
import urllib
import cStringIO

url = 'your_url'
first_param = '12'
dArrayData = [{'data' : 'first'}, {'data':'second'}]
json_to_send = json.dumps(dArrayData, separators=(',',':'), sort_keys=False)

curlClient = pycurl.Curl()
curlClient.setopt(curlClient.USERAGENT, 'curl-user-agent')

# Sets the url of the service
curlClient.setopt(curlClient.URL, url)

# Sets the request to be of the type POST
curlClient.setopt(curlClient.POST, True)

# Sets the params of the post request
send_params = 'first_param=' + first_param + '&data=' + urllib.quote(json_to_send)
curlClient.setopt(curlClient.POSTFIELDS, send_params)

# Setting the buffer for the response to be written to
bufResponse = cStringIO.StringIO()
curlClient.setopt(curlClient.WRITEFUNCTION, bufResponse.write)

# Setting to fail on error
curlClient.setopt(curlClient.FAILONERROR, True)

# Sets the time out for the connections
curlClient.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 25)
curlClient.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 25)

response = ''

try:
    # Performs the operation
    curlClient.perform()

except pycurl.error as err:
    errno, errString = err
    print '========'
    print 'ERROR sending the data:'
    print '========'
    print 'CURL error code:', errno
    print 'CURL error Message:', errString
else:
    response = bufResponse.getvalue()
    # Do what ever you want with the response.. Json it or what ever..
finally:
    curlClient.close()
    bufResponse.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The requests library is most supported and advanced way to do this.